# Business layer design - How to define rules

Tags: c#, java, oop, model, domain-driven-design

I understand that its a best practice to put your business rules in a business layer and your data access in a separate data access layer, while the entities are part of your model.

So for example i'm working with a Customer entity defined in my model, i can fetch all customers from the database via the Data access layer. I can also add a new customer, via the DAL.

However before I add the customer, i need to run a validation on it - so i guess i need to define the rules in the business layer - but i'm not quite sure how to go about it.

> Does my business layer only have methods which accept the entities as
>   parameters? Something like BLL.Customers.Validate(Model.Customer
>   customer) ?
>
> Or
>
> Does my business layer extend my Entities? Should I make the entity
>   classes like Customer partial classes? so that the BLL can extend them
>   further with business rules?

**I'm not sure how to design the business layer.**

Comment: There is an excellent discussion on validation in a domain driven design on stackoverflow. Visit the following link for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516615/validation-in-a-domain-driven-design.

Comment: This question might also be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818898/where-to-put-global-rules-validation-in-ddd/5832618#5832618

Answer (score 0):

Your entities should really carry all their own business behaviour, so there would be a Validate method on the entity itself. I also like to have a static factory method in my entities for creating an entity:

```
public class Cusotmer
{
    private long? _id;
    private string _name;
    //other attributes...

    public static Customer Create(string name)
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
    }

    public void Validate()
    {
        if(_name == null)
            throw new ValidationException("Name has not been set.");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why you need partial classes, except maybe if you're code generating your entities from a database perhaps?

Comment: If i tie the validate method with the entity and i have different validation requirements based on the usage then the entity gets bloated. I kind of like the Visitor pattern of usage.

Comment: account for the different in the one validation method with a few if statements. Or maybe you need to have different entities in different systems for the different usages: read up on bounded contexts.